# How to make page automatically refresh daily

Tags: javascript

I am using the following function to try and refresh my page every day:

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if (now.getHours() > hours ||
        (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(true); console.log("reloading"); }, timeout);
}
```

...which I call thus

```
refreshAt(00,01,00);
```

However in Chrome on my Mac it never refreshes. I have the call near the top of my script, which is in the body. The declaration is at the bottom of the script.
On my Android phone it refreshes if I change between tabs during the day, but incorrectly, and this latter worked better BEFORE I added the refresh function.
I'm puzzled.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve using refreshAt method ?

Comment: [it works??](http://jsbin.com/tiqalibiju/edit?console)

Comment: I want the page to refresh every day just after midnight local time, so that the data that it gets from elsewhere is always up to date.The javascript use getJSON to obtain that data  using a php file. You can see it in action here...
http://userweb.aanet.com.au/dangar/dirfb/meter/index.htm?region=Greater%20Sydney%20Region

Comment: Again: your code works. We cant help you to fix working code.

Comment: In that case, I have perhaps not clearly expressed the problem. I want the page to refresh without the user interacting with it in any way after they have first opened it. I would like the page to be open in the browser 365 days a year, and always refresh every day. I understand my code is good, but it does not achieve what I want it to achieve.

Comment: You're right tho Jonas, it does work in your implementation on JS Bin. There must be something elsewhere in my script that is cruelling my pitch

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of application you are working on. If it's a website or an app, the page will refresh every time the user opens it. However if the application you are dealing with is something that displays all the time with no options for user actions, then you can set up a *CRON* job. 
This also depends on what type of framework you are using, angular, react, etc. However, with plain javascript, you can set up a job that runs every day at a certain time.
This is the link to a library that I find useful. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('0 7 * * *', function() {
  /*

     *+---------------- minute (0 - 59)
      |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
      |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
      |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
      |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
      |  |  |  |  |
      *  *  *  *  * 
  */

      }, function () {
        /* This function is executed when the job stops */
      },
      true, /* Start the job right now */
      timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
    );
```

You can look at the documentation and make your own job.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using plain javascript - 
http://userweb.aanet.com.au/dangar/dirfb/meter/index.htm?region=Greater%20Sydney%20Region

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

```js
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds)
{
    var now = new Date(), then = new Date();
    then.setHours(hours,minutes,seconds,0);
    if(then.getTime()<now.getTime())
    {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
}
refreshAt(0,1,0);
```